# How to find the edit distance / levenshtein distance between a string and a language?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

Edit distance of a string x from a language S is the edit distance of x from the 'closest' string y ∈ S. Given a string x∈{0,1,...,9,(,),+,-,*,/} * , I want to find an efficient algorithm that calculates the edit distance between x and the language of simple arithmetic expressions. I think I have to use dynamic-programming as in the classic edit-distance problem, but in this case I don't know the second string to compare to the first one. Should I use somehow the language limitations? Construct a syntax diagram or syntax tree? Thank you.

P.S.: The language S of simple arithmetic expressions is defined as:

- every string that is an example of the regular expression {1|2|...|9}{0|1|2|...|9}* | 0 belongs to S
- if x ∈ S then (x) ∈ S
- if x,y ∈ S then x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y ∈ S

Comment: My intuition is that some sort of greedy algorithm should give the correct answer; i.e. try parsing the expression, and every time there's a parse error, just remove the unexpected symbol or insert the expected symbol accordingly. The tricky case seems to be like `1(3)` where the `(` is an unexpected symbol, but we need to look-ahead to know whether it's better to remove `(` or insert `+`. A two-pass algorithm should be able to deal with that by counting brackets first, but I'm not sure how to prove that it gives the true minimum number of edits.